# Get e-mail address of selected mailboxes

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to receive the mail addresse of the account that is active in mail.

So far I did the following

```
tell application "Mail"
    set selected to selected mailboxes of message viewer 1
end tell
```

and

```
tell application "Mail"
    email addresses of every account
end tell
```

But somehow i am not able do somethin like

```
tell application "Mail"
    set selectedMailboxes to selection
    set theAccount to account of selection
    return theAccount
end tell
```

The Last applescript does not work. How can I retrieve the account of the mailbox in `message vieview 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
tell application "Mail"
    try
        set selectedMailbox to item 1 of (get selected mailboxes of message viewer 1)
        set mailAddresses to email addresses of account of selectedMailbox
    on error
        display dialog "No Mailbox selected"
    end try
end tell
```

As an account can have multiple mail addresses, the class of the variable `mailAddresses` is a list even there is only one address.

Get the address you want with an index number (1-based)

```
set myAddress to item 1 of mailAddresses
```

or

```
set myAddress to second item of mailAddresses
```